# "Save to Foursquare" button not matching venue

Tags: foursquare

We accurately geolocate venues and then check whether there is a Foursquare venue for that place. Even in the US, but especially in Asia or Africa, lots of Foursquare venues are not correctly mapped. Out of concern for accuracy and not wishing to introduce duplicates into Foursquare - and, until recently, unable to update existing venues in Foursquare - we mapped and then matched our places with venues already in Foursquare.

Previously, with the iFrame-based button, there was no problem if the coordinates of our place were not exactly the same as those in Foursquare. We could attach the Foursquare venue id that corresponded to the venue in our system, and our user could save it to their Foursquare. But now the iFrame button at

```
http://foursquare.com/button.html?vid=
```

seems to have stopped working.

Now, for those previously nonexistent Foursquare venues that we added ourselves or, seemingly, where there is a very close match with the lat/long we supply, the new javascript-based button works.

But for many others, painstakingly matched over the years, because our correct locations don't match the incorrect ones carelessly entered into Foursquare, the "Save to Foursquare" button is useless on our site.

I can imagine that this would also be a problem where the venue has been re-located and a publisher's location metadata reflects the old location.

Why not just use Foursquare venue ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Foursquare venue IDs with our more modern widgets: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/widgets. The embedding pattern is a little different but there is a `vid` key you can pass in to have the widget be associated with a particular venue.

Comment: It does indeed look as if the information I need could be extrapolated from the various instructions on that page. 

Having a "Save to Foursquare" button on our page is a convenience for any of our users who may have a Foursquare account. It's a 'nice to have' but not a 'must have'. It's something I have again, one day when I have time.

The old iFrame thingy was easy. Have you got about a ready-to-paste sample?

Comment: @KenAra Yep, take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/octopi/7533191. Basically instead of including the venue ID in the iframe URL, you put it in as a data attribute in the HTML.

Comment: cool, thanks! That looks good. I tried something like `s.vid=` in the javascript and that didn't work. I expect this will be easy now.